# Using a XAML file as a vector Image Source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, vector-graphics

I would like to be able to use vector graphics, preferably defined in XAML, as the Source of an Image control, just like I can currently use a raster image like a PNG. That way I could easily mix and match between bitmap and vector images, like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Image Source="Images/Namespace.png"/>
    <Image Source="Images/Module.xaml"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Module.xaml would most likely have `<DrawingImage>` as its root element instead of `<UserControl>`.

Actually, what I'm really going for is this, so my ViewModel could select either a raster or vector image at its discretion:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}"/>
```

Is this possible? Can Image.Source load XAML classes from a given URI? Or is it only able to load bitmap resources?

Comment: Makes me wonder... Why would using a XAML image in WPF/Silverlight be so difficult, or not supported natively... considering that WPF/Silverlight is based on XAML!

Answer (score 21):

You can simply reference your vector graphics as StaticResources:

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource MyImage}" />
```

Store the images in a ResourceDictionary as DrawImage's.  Expression Blend can help you generate this stuff:

```
<ResourceDictionary
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

   <DrawingImage x:Key="MyImage">
      <DrawingImage.Drawing>
         <DrawingGroup>
            <DrawingGroup.Children>
               <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black" Geometry="M 333.393,... 100.327 Z "/>
               <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black" Geometry="F1 M 202.309,... Z "/>
                      :
            </DrawingGroup.Children>
         </DrawingGroup>
     </DrawingImage.Drawing>
   </DrawingImage>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Sure. Doesn't help me with the databinding scenario, though (at least not directly).

Comment: Simple but elegant way when combined with "Method 3" discussed in [this blog post](https://liftcodeplay.com/2015/09/14/converting-vectorsvg-images-into-xaml/)

Answer (score 2):

1) Add the DrawingImage.xaml to the project and set its properties to 'BuildAction=Content' and 'Copy Always'. Or else you can dynamically load the XAML from outside since the logic I am going to explain will work for loose-xaml also.

2) Write a Converter to convert the XAML uri to UIELement, in your case it will be always DrawingImage

```
public class FileToUIElementConverter :IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream((string)parameter, FileMode.Open); 
        return XamlReader.Load(fileStream) as DrawingImage;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

3) Write the XAML as below

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:FileToUIElementConverter x:Key="uriToUIElementConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource uriToUIElementConverter},ConverterParameter=ImageDrawing.xaml}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I don't think FileStream can load from a compiled resource (pack:// URI), can it?

Comment: There's a converter that handles resources here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21588195/418362

Answer (score 1):

Embed the XAML resource (DrawingImage) with type 'Resource'.  It is then not a separate file and can be directly referenced via a URI, as in your original example -- BUT the URI is non-trivial.  You have to figure out Microsoft's "pack" URI syntax and use that.

Comment: It isn't documented, but the "pack" URI internals are not loaded into memory until _after_ you instantiate your first UIElement.  So, trying to use it in App.cs (before your MainWindow.xaml has even been loaded) is quite frustrating.  Instead, use it in your MainWindow_Load handler.