# WPF Using XAML Image Source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to show my vector image in Image.Source with `XamlReader`. I have a XAML resource like that.

```
<Canvas Width="76" Height="76" ClipToBounds="True" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
<Path Fill="#FF000000" Height="76" Stretch="Fill" Width="76">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="M21,30.0001L55.9999,30.0001 55.9999,50 21,50 21,30.0001z M52,28L37,28C38,25,39.4999,24.0001,39.4999,24.0001L50.75,24C51.3023,24,52,24.6977,52,25.25L52,28z" />
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Created a binding from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107334/using-a-xaml-file-as-a-vector-image-source). But It does not work when I try to use it with:

```
<Image Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource uriToUIElementConverter},ConverterParameter=images/Folder.xaml}"/>
```

The file's property `Build Action=Resource`. The converter `uriTOUIElementConverter` is that:

```
public class FileToUIElementConverter :IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream((string)parameter, FileMode.Open); 
        return XamlReader.Load(fileStream) as DrawingImage;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

When I try to build project it gives me these errors:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
```

I edited converter like this:

```
Stream fileStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ASSEMBLYNAME;component/"+(string) parameter)).Stream;
```

But it does not work again. What should I do to get it worked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Path that you need supplied do [Application.GetResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596994.aspx) is relative to the application package.

Example:

I have XAML file Images/Folder.xaml. **Build Action for Folder.xaml is Resource**.

**Folder.xaml**

```
<DrawingImage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="LimeGreen">
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>

                <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero"
                              Figures="M21,30.0001L55.9999,30.0001 55.9999,50 21,50 21,30.0001z M52,28L37,28C38,25,39.4999,24.0001,39.4999,24.0001L50.75,24C51.3023,24,52,24.6977,52,25.25L52,28z" />

            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```

**Converter :**

```
public class FileToUIElementConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string path = parameter.ToString();

        StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative));
        if (sri != null)
        {
            using (Stream stream = sri.Stream)
            {
                var logo = XamlReader.Load(stream) as DrawingImage;

                if (logo != null)
                {
                    return logo;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("Resource not found");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<Image x:Name="ImageLogo" Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FileToUiElementConverter}, ConverterParameter=images/folder.xaml}"/>
```

Comment: Just in case, there is a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69026704/7585517) but tailored for the `<icon>.xaml` files from "Visual Studio Image Library"