# How to use xaml as image source

Tags: c#, image, xaml

I am creating a WPF project and have to enter a lot of images. The originals of the images are SVGs and I have to convert them in different formats.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107334/using-a-xaml-file-as-a-vector-image-source) page where an xaml could be included as imagesource.

Is it also possible to load a imagesource-xaml by path like

```
<Image Source="Resources/Images/123.xaml"/>
```

I am happy about any idea.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107334/using-a-xaml-file-as-a-vector-image-source

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a XAML file as a vector Image Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107334/using-a-xaml-file-as-a-vector-image-source)

Comment: Thanks to both of you but this is exactly what I already saw and have linked in my question. I need to load it from the file itself and not from an reosurce inside and referencing with staticresource.