# Inkscape (vector graphic)

Tags: c#, wpf, svg, inkscape

I want to have nice looking vector graphic in my application. And who doesn't? =D

After some researching I found that there is `SVG` file format (and some others), but `WPF` (despite its credo *vector graphics, blablabla*) doesn't supports it.

I tried two svg libraries, but they are really crap (so I will not say their names).

Then I found what `Inkscape` (free svg-editor) can save svg-files as xaml-files. Here is a peace of such file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform">
    <Canvas Name="svg2" Width="744" Height="1052">
        <Canvas.Resources>
        <!--Unknown tag: inkscape:perspective-->
        </Canvas.Resources>
        <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
        <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
        <Canvas Name="layer1">
            <Canvas Name="g2987">
                <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path2999" Fill="#FFE9E9FF">
                <Path.Data><PathGeometry Figures="m 299.04734 376.6985  ........
```

Now my question is how can I use those xaml-files? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3528493/1997232) answer, but still I have no clue how to display my nice looking vector stuff inside button. It's `Viewbox` located in *another* xaml (not in one where window/application is defined).

How do I organize it in a way to be able easily display it, to example:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Content> ... display it here somehow </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

And to keep it as **separate file** (don't copy content or whatever), so that I can easily **change** it or edit with Inkscape.

I thought about resource dictionaries, yet I can figure out how would that looks like.

P.S.: from other point of view, I could write small converter, so that original files will be kept as `SVG`, then I export them as `xaml` and finally run my converter to make it **something** what I then can easily assign as content to buttons. I need guidance of how would that something looks like, to still be **separate xaml** and how actually attach it as content to a button.

Comment: To downvotes, to whom is unclear what I am asking: **How to assign `Viewbox` to button content?** Or what should I do to assign `xaml` generated by `Inkscape` as button content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start by creating ResourceDictionary
add your exported view boxes to it and add a unique key to them

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform" x:Key="buttonContent">
        <Canvas Name="svg2" Width="744" Height="1052">
        ...
```

merge the dictionary to your window or user control or even whole application

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ButtonDictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        ...
```

then use it as follows to use with your button

```
<Button Content="{StaticResource buttonContent}">
```

this is a sample to create resource dictionary and use them

Comment: `x:Shared="False"` is important addition to this answer. The final solution (which I am using year later) is to keep `Canvas` as a root element for svg file, so that bunch of canvases (one for each svg file) then combined into single resource dictionary, all of them have key and then I use `ViewBox` in place where I want to display them (because I want to be able to set viewbox size).