# Showing saved Xaml Canvas through binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, svg, binding

I'm saving an svg image as xaml string in a database. Next I record this xaml string in a property of a class (MyClass.XamlString) .

On my form I have a Canvas, and I want MyClass.XamlString to be the child of the canvas.

This is what I have:

```
        Dim MyBinding As New Binding("XamlString")
        MyBinding.Source = MyClass
        MyBinding.Converter = New clsXamlToCanvasConverter
        CanvasOnForm.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, MyBinding)
```

and

```
Friend Class clsXamlToCanvasConverter
Implements IValueConverter

Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
    Dim ConvertedCanvas As Canvas = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse("<Canvas xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"">" & value & "</Canvas>")
    Return ConvertedCanvas
End Function

Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Function
End Class
```

In debugging I see the clsXamlToCanvasConverter creates a canvas with children from the xaml string, this is working correctly although you might say the extra canvas is redundant.

My guess is this is where I'm going wrong: CanvasOnForm.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, MyBinding)

The code runs fine, the problem is I don't see the image displayed.

I've been searching a lot on this and I've seen this post [WPF What is the correct way of using SVG files as icons in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526366/wpf-what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-svg-files-as-icons-in-wpf) , but apparently this hasn't helped me out.

Any ideas?

Comment: If `CanvasOnForm` is actually a Canvas, the binding won't work because Canvas has no Content property. You may use a ContentControl or ContentPresenter instead.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. If you enter it as answer I can mark it as correct answer.