# How to bind to an unbindable property without violating MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, svg, mvvm, data-binding

I am using [SharpVector's SvgViewBox](https://sharpvectors.codeplex.com/) to show static resource images like this:

```
<svgc:SvgViewbox Source="/Resources/label.svg"/>
```

which works fine.  However, I wish to control what image is shown through a binding to a view model.

The problem I'm experiencing is that the `Source` property of SvgViewbox is not bindable.

How can I get around this limitation without violating MVVM (e.g., passing the control into the view model and modifying it there)?

Answer (score 10):

What you are looking for is called attached properties. MSDN offers a topic on it with the title "[Custom Attached Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903943%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)"

In your case it may look as simple as this

```
namespace MyProject.Extensions 
{
    public class SvgViewboxAttachedProperties : DependencyObject
    {
        public static string GetSource(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string) obj.GetValue(SourceProperty);
        }

        public static void SetSource(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnSourceChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var svgControl = obj as SvgViewbox;
            if (svgControl != null)
            {
                var path = (string)e.NewValue;
                svgControl.Source = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path) ? default(Uri) : new Uri(path);
            }                
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Source",
                typeof (string), typeof (SvgViewboxAttachedProperties),
                                    // default value: null
                new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSourceChanged));
    }
}
```

XAML to use it

```
<SvgViewbox Margin="0 200" 
    local:SvgViewboxAttachedProperties.Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}" />
```

Note that `local` is the namespace prefix and it should point to your assembly/namespace where that class is located at, i.e. `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Extensions;assembly=MyProject"`.

Then only use your attached property (`local:Source`) and never the `Source` property.

The new attached property `local:Source` is of type System.Uri. To update the image first assign null then the filename/filepath again.

Comment: This worked for me with a minor tweak. Since `svgControl.Source` is a `Uri`, set it using `svgControl.Source = new Uri((string)e.NewValue);`

Comment: @burnttoast11: Thanks, I fixed it. Originally I wrote the code only based on the question w/o looking at the concrete API of the control in question.