# is it possible to create SVG files in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, svg

I am new to `WPF` `C#.Net` and got a project to build UI using `SVG` in `wpf`,
i have been searching for a while and couldn't find an answer.
so my question is:
is it possible to work with `SVG(scalable vector graphics)` in `WPF`?
if so,then How?
any help would be appreciated .Thanks!

Comment: The sort answer is no. WPF uses its own format (xaml) and does not work with svg. If you want to convert a SVG into XAML, you may try Inkscape or  svg2xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, no there is no support for SVG.

But have a look at this question, where they explain how to convert it:
[WPF What is the correct way of using SVG files as icons in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526366/wpf-what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-svg-files-as-icons-in-wpf)

And here as well:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/22978b1c-be4d-475d-8a57-371f324b4697/does-wpf-support-svg?forum=wpf

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no direct support for Svg in Wpf application. 
I have used [SharpVector](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/127039/SharpVectors-SVG-Reloaded-An-Introduction) Library.

> C# library for converting SVG to WPF and viewing SVG files in WPF
>   applications directly

**Usage:**

```
namespace: xmlns:svg="http://sharpvectors.codeplex.com/svgc/"

<svg:SvgCanvas Name="svgCanvas" Source="yourPath.svg"/>
```