# Extracting SVG data into XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, svg

I'm trying to extract SVG data and display it on a WPF form for a project I am working on. The problem is that I can't get the XAML to display the same way that the SVG does

SVG Image

[image: SVG Image]

SVG Code

```
<ellipse transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -11.7477 28.3614)"
         fill="#6DBE45"
         cx="28.4" cy="28.4"
         rx="32.5" ry="23.5"/>

<ellipse transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 4.1498 66.7412)"
         fill="#991B1E"
         cx="82.6" cy="28.4"
         rx="32.5" ry="23.5"/>
```

XAML Image

[image]

XAML Code

```
<Canvas>
  <Ellipse Width="65" Height="47" Fill="Green">
            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <MatrixTransform Matrix="0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -11.7477 28.3614" />
                    <TranslateTransform X="28.4" Y="28.4"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
  </Ellipse>
  <Ellipse Width="65" Height="47" Fill="Red">
            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <MatrixTransform Matrix="0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 4.1498 66.7412" />
                    <TranslateTransform X="82.6" Y="28.4"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
  </Ellipse>
</Canvas>
```

What I'm doing:

```
Height = ry (radiusY) * 2
Width = rx (radiusX) * 2

Matrix transform = transform values
Translate trasnform = cx (coordiante x), cy (coordiante y)
```

I am not sure why they are displaying very differently when all the values (in my head) seem to make sense

Comment: How do you *extract data*? You can use Inkscape to convert svg into microsoft xaml. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3526366/1997232) also.

Comment: @Sinatr Extracting the XML from the SVG using Linq then picking out the values one by one. Just used a XAML example because it's easier to show what's going on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might better use `Path` elements with EllipseGeometries. The advantage compared to `Ellipse` elements is that you can explicitly specify the `Center`, `RadiusX` and `RadiusY` properties.

Now you could use the exact values from your SVG:

```
<Canvas>
    <Path Fill="Green">
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry
                Center="28.4 28.4"
                RadiusX="32.5" RadiusY="23.5"
                Transform="0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -11.7477 28.3614"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Path Fill="Red">
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry
                Center="82.6 28.4"
                RadiusX="32.5" RadiusY="23.5"
                Transform="0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 4.1498 66.7412"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

The result is this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed