# How to load image of type XAML in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, svg

Hello guys I want to know what is the proper way to load `.xaml` image type since `.svg` format is not applicable for WPF. I downloaded the program Inkscape and managed to convert an `.svg` image file to `.xaml`. However I am stuck at the point on how to load the image. Can you explain to me how to load the xaml type images inside the XAML?

Comment: Please refer to [WPF What is the correct way of using SVG files as icons in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526366/wpf-what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-svg-files-as-icons-in-wpf) there are some options there, one is to convert the svg..

Comment: I place the content of the generated xaml in the Resources Dictionary and add a `x:key` that corresponds to the image usage. Like `RedCloseCrossIcon` or `GreenAddIcon`. I have used InkScape as well so you will have to resolve names of the paths and fills.