# Use UIElement from XAML file in a window's XAML code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have multiple XAML files containing a UserControl (they are SVG images converted to XAML). In C#, to have that image in a Grid for example, I would use a XamlReader and add the root element to the grid's children.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("example.xaml");
UIElement rootElement = (UIElement) XamlReader.Load(sr.BaseStream);
theGrid.Children.Add(rootElement);
```

How can I do the same in XAML (where I would use a path to the image XAML from a binding)?

I am looking for this approach in order to follow the MVVM principle of separating UI from code.

Comment: You may perhaps bind the Content property of a ContentControl, with a Binding Converter that returns the result of XamlReader.Load.

Comment: MVVM != no codebehind.  UI code is perfectly fine in your codebehind. This is UI code. It's also really weird, and there's probably a better way of accomplishing your goals.

Comment: Most obvious approach is to declare the converted XAML as resources and then reference the resource. But, even with more context and a [mcve] there would be many possible ways to approach the problem, and as stated, even more. Your question is way too broad. Try _something_, ask for help if you can't get that _specific_ thing to work.

Comment: Thank you, @Clemens. That best answered my issue and was the approach I went with. I'll mark it as the solution should you provide it as an answer.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please note that you can also write (and later accept) an answer to your own question. Just post your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You may perhaps bind the Content property of a ContentControl, with a Binding Converter that returns the result of XamlReader.Load.

Solution suggested by [Clemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136211/clemens).

Answer (score 0):

[WPF What is the correct way of using SVG files as icons in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526366/wpf-what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-svg-files-as-icons-in-wpf)

Describes the problem.
Bottom line is there are tools to convert SVG to xaml.
Google around a bit you Will find plenty of tools.
The link also has useful information.

An SVG is An image, i also don't see the link with mvvm. Unless your image is not fixed. Based on your question it appears you want a fixed converted xaml in another xaml.

I think it is a matter of copy-paste the relevant part in your target xaml control.There is a little overhead.

If  the image is not fixed, you load a string to fill the path. That would be bindable by mvvm in a viewmodel that loads and assigns a property with inotifypropertychanged.