# How can I do a kebab menu (three dots menu) button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

I have an WPF app and I am trying to know what is the best way to implement a kebab menu (three dots menu) button in WPF. Similar to this:

[image]

or similar to this in MS Edge (but vertical):

[image]

I am using .NET Standard 4.5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526366/wpf-what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-svg-files-as-icons-in-wpf

Comment: if you are free to involve third party assets, you could include the fontawesome font where there's such an icon here: https://fontawesome.com/icons/ellipsis-vertical?s=solid&f=classic

Comment: You can just use ⋮

Comment: @Jodrell I am not able to understand what is the relationship between my question and the possible solution you proposed.

Comment: @DiegoD Thanks for the suggestion. Honestly I would like to avoid any third-party dependencies.

Comment: @Rodri if you want an Icon on a button, you could use a SVG for that icon. However, in this case, the "Kebab" has its own Unicode representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
    <Button VerticalAlignment="Top"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Width="30"
            Height="30">
        <TextBlock Text="⋮"/>
    </Button>
```

Or alternatively using xml format character encoding

```
    <Button VerticalAlignment="Top"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Width="30"
            Height="30">
        <TextBlock Text='&#8942;'/>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Hi Andy, quick question if you don't mind. Why declaring a TextBlock inside the button and not set the the button's content property directly?

Comment: When you set content on a button code in the button class ( or maybe it's buttonbase ) creates a textblock automatically and sets it's text property for you.  
I put a textblock so it's clear you could set font size or make it bold or whatever you like on that.

But also. I tried a textblock first to prove I was going to get the three dots. Then pasted it in to a button.